# What is difference between word incise and excise?

Tags: word-usage

Are incise and excise synonym?What are the uses conditions for incise and excise?

I found multiple meaning for excise as excise can be both noun and verb. But in my class note both words meaning is surgically cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Incise**: to cut into; cut marks, figures, etc., upon. [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/incise)

When a surgeon *incises*, he is cutting *into* something. A sculptor might make small *incisions* into a face to give it character.

> **Excise**: to cut out or off, as a tumor. [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/excise)

When a surgeon *excises*, he is cutting (something) *out of* something. The definition mentions a tumor. An excision is removing something bad.

Comment: That means both are same.

Comment: @sgc No. The difference is *into* and *out of*. The purpose of an incision, at least medicially, is to cut *into* something. Excising may involve an incision, but its purpose is to cut something else out of something. You are making incisions in open heart surgery, when you cut in order to see what is underneath. Your primary purpose is excision when a brain tumor is removed.

Comment: @sgc - That means both are similar.

Comment: No, they both involve cutting, cut out is not cut into. They are opposites.